# Reflection of Electromagnetic wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, reflection

I have a question that I have found the solution to but does not match with the answer given, here goes the question,

A plane electromagnetic wave propagating in air with $ \vec{E} = (8\hat{i} + 6\hat{j} + 5\hat{k})e^{i(\omega t + 3x -4y) }$, where $\hat{i},\hat{j}$ and $ \hat{k}$  are unit vectors. This plane wave is incident on a perfectly conducting slab placed at $x = 0$. Electric field of the reflected wave is?

**Attempt at the Solution**: since the slab is perfectly conducting the electric field will undergo a phase shift of 180 degrees hence the amplitude of the reflected wave will be $-8\hat{i} -6\hat{j} - 5\hat{k})$. And the propagation vector which is $3x - 4y $would change to $ -3x-4y $ as there won't be any change in propagation vector in y-direction, Hence the reflected wave will be given by,
$$\vec{E} =( -8\hat{i} -6\hat{j} - 5\hat{k}) e^{i(\omega t - 3x -4y) }$$

Answer is given as :
$$\vec{E} =( -8\hat{i} +6\hat{j} - 5\hat{k}) e^{i(\omega t - 3x -4y) }$$

Comment: Write mathematical expression on $LATEX$ please

Comment: Im very sorry, But I am new to this and I dont know how to.

Comment: For a tutorial on how to typeset mathematical formulae see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please also read carefully [our guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://math.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/).

Comment: That's the answer given as part of the answer key, the question appeared in a competitive exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incident electromagnetic wave is coming in along the $-3\hat i + 4 \hat j$ direction and if the electric field vector direction is $8 \hat i + 6 \hat j + 5 \hat k$ then $(-3\hat i + 4 \hat j) \cdot (8 \hat i + 6 \hat j + 5 \hat k) = -24 + 24 =0$ which shows that the direction of electromagnetic wave propagation is perpendicular to electric field vector.

You answer of electromagnetic wave direction $+3\hat i + 4 \hat j$ and electric field vector $-8 \hat i - 6 \hat j - 5 \hat k$ cannot be correct because $(+3\hat i + 4 \hat j) \cdot (-8 \hat i - 6 \hat j - 5 \hat k) = -24 - 24 \ne 0$ showing that the electric field vector is no longer perpendicular to the direction of motion of the wave whereas the given answer does have the electric field vector perpendicular to the direction of propagation of the electromagnetic wave.

You might find that drawing a sketch in the $x-y$ plane might help?

Comment: okay, thanks a lot!, I will try that and get back to this.

Comment: Also what about the 180 degree phase shift the reflected wave undergoes, given that this is a perfectly conducting slab.

Comment: Okay, I got the solution right now, assuming any wave would undergo a complete 180 degree phase shift was wrong, to fit the condition of dot product between propagation vector and polarization vector the j-component in this case does not undergo phase shift and I worked out the boundary conditions which gives the same answer

Comment: thanks a lot  for pointing out the condition the reflecting wave must meet, that helped a lot.